# Bandwidth Consumption in TCP connection when not in use

Tags: networking

How much bandwidth does a TCP connection (on a port xxxx) would be consumed if virtually no data packet transfer is taking place.
Actually I need to write an application which will create a TCP connection to a server on a port xxxx, and then both the Server and the client will become idle ( that is, they will transmit very small packets of 500KB-600KB after a very long span of time; may be after 6 or 7 hours ). The server would be handling more than 10,000 connections at a time.
An important thing to remember is that the TCP session will be maintained for the life time of the communicating parties (until client or server is tuned off).
Now the question is, What would be the bandwidth cost in this scenario. Will a common Web Server would be enough for this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero, unless TCP KEEPALIVE is enabled on the socket, in which case it is still essentially zero.

But 500-600Kb is not 'very small packets'. Do you mean 500-600 *bytes?*

Comment: Sorry,I meant a very small amount of packets with aggregated weight of 500KB. An other question is that if I program the server side script in Java and send every TCP connection to a separate thread, will it cost too high in the sense of "Computational cost" ?

Comment: @Tariq I don't know what 'aggregated weight' means but 500KB isn't a small payload however you distribute it. There is no computational cost of a thread that isn't receiving any data.

Comment: aggregated weight means there might be 100 chunks of 5KB packets sent one after one. And thanks a lot for your help full responses.